# Can my Samsung Galaxy Book3 i-5 1335u support 2 external displays?

Tags: external-display

I would like to know if I could connect 2 external monitors in FHD as extensions (not mirroring) to my laptop.My laptop is a Samsung Galaxy Book3 I-5 1335U with intel iris XE graphics 80eu.  The ports are one HDMI 1.4, two USB A 3.2 Gen 1, two USB C 3.1 Gen 1. Will either the USB A or USB C port support two external displays in FHD? Can I use a USB A or USB C to HDMI adapter? Or is there another way? If both USB A and C support displays then which one would be better for only FHD? I plan to use them for stock trading. I appreciate any replys.